# Animating divs makes Edge/Safari repaint/layout parent container

Tags: javascript, css, browser, safari, microsoft-edge

I have the following scenario:

- There are a couple thousand divs (`.lifeevent`) inside the same container (`#eventContainer`). They are being animated and have their `left` and `top` properties changed during each frame, but in no particular relation to each other (which makes animating the parent container instead of all the children impossible).
- The parent has `position: absolute` and all of the children divs are also `position: absolute`.
- Animation code is very simple (only changes the style attribute of the child elements) and uses requestAnimationFrame
- Works smoothly on Chrome
- Near-impossible to use on Edge and Safari
- Profiling the animation with Edge shows me thousands of these Layout events:

[image: layout/repaint problem]

So I believe the problem here is that every animated div makes the parent container's layout to be reevaluated. And when that happens thousands of times per frame, it's no wonder it's sluggish. Does anyone have an idea why that happens?

Comment: Just reduce your count of <div>. A "couple thousand" instances with attached animations will kill the beefiest system. I'm impressed your Chrome handles this :)

Comment: Not possible. Also, the animation happens within one loop, it's not attached individually to each element. Besides, I'm really interested in understanding why the children divs cause a layer layout on the parent.

Comment: Have you tried using *transforms* instead of setting `top` and `left`?

Comment: Yes, I have, these work even worse on Edge and Safari for some reason. I'm also using transform3d(0, 0, 0) in combination with top/left to trigger hardware acceleration where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit of the performance problem was the triggering of a browser layout for each animated element (which in turn, caused a heavy layout on the parent as well). After debugging with the Chrome timeline tool, I found out that this was happening because of "forced synchronous layouts" (in my case due to alternating gets and sets on each of the elements' width/top/left style properties). A great guide to dealing with forced synchronous layouts can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/758790/Debugging-and-solving-the-Forced-Synchronous-Layou). It certainly helped me a lot with my problem. After taking care of the order in which gets/sets happened, all of the animated elements' style updates happened only with a single layout, which solved the peformance under Edge and Safari.